# Laravel Forge SSH on windows not recognized

Tags: windows, ssh-keys, putty

I decided to try out the Laravel Forge, but I'm having trouble with the SSH keys. I use digitalocean.com for the VMs and have used SSH keys with success many times before.

However when I paste my public key into Forge (which adds it to the server) I'm not able to connect to it. I use Putty and I get the following error:

> Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)

Key was generated using puttygen and was added to pageant.

I have tried using the very same key files as my other VM and tried creating a new one, but all without luck.

I'm hoping someone can help me out here.

Edit: here is my putty log http://pastebin.com/ZGmm8Mcv

Comment: I don't know the putty equivalent but you need to show the output of `ssh -vvv`. "No Supported authentication methods available" sounds like no public key was sent when trying to connect.

Comment: i updated my question with a log

Comment: `Event Log: Trying Pageant key #0` `Event Log: Server refused public key` - looks like a clear case of the offered key not being accepted. I doubt using laravel forge fundamentally changes how ssh access works - you should IMO debug it like any other ssh access problem (check keys exist on the server, check they match the key being offered).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer from @alysdal worked perfectly for me. Just to have the steps on this site as well:

You have to modify your public key and transform your generated key from this form

```
---- BEGIN SSH2 PUBLIC KEY ----
Comment: "rsa-key-20160907"
AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABJQAAAIEA3nfXA8oSOGcx1OJg0/2dkgH2gDXhN6GX5/QW
KyPif8tHYh/GBvwsnoLyPAUNq9D9wv/g+DxBr1nGpIwIAICxycHNEq7iNGcImhWs
rlEWBWRE8fYG4Qpx0/CKDcNsCZzjiu0exwp4pw5nDcZQOsr321bly3edRgfgmgix
rzLaOCk=
---- END SSH2 PUBLIC KEY ----
```

into this form

```
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABJQAAAIEA3nfXA8oSOGcx1OJg0/2dkgH2gDXhN6GX5/QWKyPif8tHYh/GBvwsnoLyPAUNq9D9wv/g+DxBr1nGpIwIAICxycHNEq7iNGcImhWsrlEWBWRE8fYG4Qpx0/CKDcNsCZzjiu0exwp4pw5nDcZQOsr321bly3edRgfgmgixrzLaOCk= user@host
```

which means:

1. Remove first two lines and the last line.
2. Join the remaining lines into one single line without whitespaces
3. Insert `ssh-rsa` with one trailing space at the beginning of the file
4. Optional: You can append `<user>@<host>` at the end of the file preceded with a whitespace.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out putty and openssh have incompatibilities. I modified my ssh key according to they following guide and it now work seamlessly.

[How To Fix “Server Refused Our Key” Error That Caused By Putty Generated RSA Public Key](http://www.walkernews.net/2009/03/22/how-to-fix-server-refused-our-key-error-that-caused-by-putty-generated-rsa-public-key/)